# Conditional type for TypeName giving error

Tags: javascript, typescript

The following type is from the [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types):

```
export type TypeName<T> =
  T extends string ? 'string' :
  T extends number ? 'number' :
  T extends boolean ? 'boolean' :
  T extends undefined ? 'undefined' :
  T extends Function ? 'function' :
  'object';
```

However trying to create a function that behaves that way gives an error:

```
export type TypeName<T> =
  T extends string ? 'string' :
  T extends number ? 'number' :
  T extends boolean ? 'boolean' :
  T extends undefined ? 'undefined' :
  T extends Function ? 'function' :
  'object';

function typeName<T>(t: T): TypeName<T> {
  return typeof t; // ERROR: type '"string"' is not assignable to type 'TypeName<T>'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that conditional types do not follow the control flow within the function.

The relevant issue is : https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912

e.g. the following (from the mentioned issue) results in a similar error:

```
type SomeConditionalType<T> = T extends string ? 1 : -1;
function fn<T>(arg: T): SomeConditionalType<T> {
    if (typeof arg === "string") {
        return 1; // ERROR: not assignable to SomeConditionalType<T>
    } else {
        return -1; // ERROR: not assignable to SomeConditionalType<T>
    }
}
```

## Workaround

The simplest workaround is to use a type assertion within the function e.g.

```
export type TypeName<T> =
  T extends string ? 'string' :
  T extends number ? 'number' :
  T extends boolean ? 'boolean' :
  T extends undefined ? 'undefined' :
  T extends Function ? 'function' :
  'object';

function typeName<T>(t: T): TypeName<T> {
  return typeof t as TypeName<T>;
}
```